# php - Android User Registration and Login

Tags: php, android, mysql, authentication, registration

I'm trying to write an Android Registration and Log in system. I looked at the code here https://github.com/andreipop/Android-Login-App as a reference. The data was saved in sqlite in that example. I was wondering how could I transfer the database to my server? probably use php with mySQL? Thanks,

Comment: Check this tutorial explained about login and registration with PHP, MySQL and SQLite [Android Login and Registration with PHP, MySQL and SQLite](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/)

Answer (score 0):

you have to know a little bit of mysql and also have knowledge of PHP, you can go to 000webhost.com and create an account which lets you host websites with access to mysql for free.There you can easily test your code in php & mysql for free.